# Correspondence of ideals between rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, ideals

Let $f:A \to B$ be a homomorphism of rings $A,B$.

Then there is a map

$e:\{$ ideals of $A\} \to\{$ ideals of $B\}$,

which sends each ideal of $A$ to $f(A)B$. I cannot understand why $f(A)B$ is an ideal of $B$. For example, I cannot prove that the summation is closed  in $f(A)B$, namely, for any  $a,a'  \in A$ and $b,b'  \in B$ there are   $ a'' \in A$ and $ b'' \in B$ such that

$f(a)b + f(a')b' =f(a'')b''.$

---

After comments

This is the book of *Undergraduate commutatie algebra Reid Miles A*, page 87 section 6.3 Ideals in $A$ and $S^
{-1}A$.

I repeat here.

> Quite generally, given a ring homomorphism $\varphi:A\to B$, there is
>   a coresopondence
>
> $e:\{$ ideals of $A\} \to\{$ ideals of $B\}$, given by
>   $e(I)=\varphi(I)B=IB$ called extension  and ....

I cannot understand what does the notaion $e(I)=\varphi(I)B=IB$ mean ?

Comment: Shouldn't it send every ideal $I$ of $A$ to $f(I)B?$

Comment: What you mean? I omitted the word prime. Is it still not correct?

Comment: As written, your map $e$ is constant

Comment: The notation $\varphi(I)B$ has the meaning I wrote in the answer. $e(I)$ is just notation, and writing $I$ instead of $\varphi(I)$ I guess is abuse of notation when $\varphi$ happens to be injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $f(I)B$ doesn't mean $\{f(a)b:a\in I, b\in B\}$, but rather
$$
f(I)B = \left\{\sum_{i\in I}f(a_i)b_i:a_i\in I, b_i\in B, I\text{ is finite} \right\}.
$$
Indeed, if you only take the set of products, you will not have an ideal. For example, let $k$ be a field and $A=k[x,y]\subset k[x,y,z,w] = B$. The extension of the ideal $(x,y)\subset A$ contains the element $xz+yw$, which is irreducible, so it is not of the form $f(a)b$.

Comment: The notation $f(I)B$ means the minimal ideal which contains the set $\{f(a)b; a \in I, b \in B\}$. Intuitively, I understand that the element $xz+yw$ is irreducible in $k[x,y,z,w]$, but I cannot prove it.

Comment: @JeanBillie Eisenstein's criterion shows it is irreducible. Or, since it is quadratic, the only way it could be reducible is if it was the product of two linear forms, and write down such a product and show directly that it cannot equal $xz+yw$.